# .Net core angular template dockerfile error

Tags: docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create an image using the .net core angular spa template in visual studio 2017. I keep receiving the npm error 127. Even though i can see the npm run build command being executed and it gets past this step. I have tried installing node on the image at the beginning of the build. No success there either. 
This is what my dockerfile looks like.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AngularNetCoreDockerApp/AngularNetCoreDockerApp.csproj", "AngularNetCoreDockerApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "AngularNetCoreDockerApp/AngularNetCoreDockerApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AngularNetCoreDockerApp"
RUN dotnet build "AngularNetCoreDockerApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AngularNetCoreDockerApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AngularNetCoreDockerApp.dll"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up having to do with the dockerfile. I ended up using this

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.301-sdk AS builder
WORKDIR /source

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

COPY ./ ./

RUN dotnet publish "./angular-app.csproj" --output "./dist" --configuration Release --no-restore

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.1-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /source/dist .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "angular-app.dll"]
```

Found the answer [**HERE**](https://hjerpbakk.com/blog/2018/06/25/aspnet-react-and-docker)

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up splitting build into multiple stages.

First I've deleted target PublishRunWebpack from *.csproj file, to make sure, that app won't build spa during publish.

After that my Dockerfile looked like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM node:latest AS node-packages
WORKDIR /web
COPY "ProjectFolder/ClientApp/package.json" .
COPY "ProjectFolder/ClientApp/package-lock.json" .
RUN npm install

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS dotnet-packages

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ProjectFolder/ProjectFile.csproj", "ProjectFolder/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ProjectFolder/ProjectFile.csproj"

FROM node-packages AS node-build
WORKDIR /web
COPY ProjectFolder/ClientApp .
RUN npm run build --prod

FROM dotnet-packages AS dotnet-build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ProjectFolder"
RUN dotnet build "ProjectFile.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
RUN dotnet publish "ProjectFile.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM node-build AS node-publish
FROM dotnet-build AS dotnet-publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=dotnet-publish /app/publish .
WORKDIR /app/ClientApp/dist
COPY --from=node-publish /web/dist .

WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectFile.dll"]
```